# Geometrically, why do we need independent columns in a matrix $A$ when computing the projection matrix onto the column space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, least-squares, projection-matrices

Consider an attempt to find the line $f(t)=C+Gt+Ht$ that best approximates a set of points using least squares.

This is a contrived example to try to explain what exactly goes wrong when we have non-independent columns in a matrix $A$ that is part of a linear system $Ax=b$.

Let's say the points are $(0,1),(1,5),(2,1),(3,1),(4,7)$. Using the proposed line, we have the following system of equations

$$C=1$$
$$C+G+H=5$$
$$C+2G+2H=1$$
$$C+3G+3H=1$$
$$C+4G+4H=7$$

which in matrix form is $Ax=b$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 1&1&1\\ 1&2&2\\ 1&3&3\\ 1&4&4\\ \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} C\\ G\\ H\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 5\\ 1\\ 1\\ 7\end{bmatrix}$$

This system does not have a solution. We can see this by row reducing it to

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} C\\ G\\ H\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 4\\ -8\\ -12\\ -10\end{bmatrix}$$

Finding the least squares solution involves solving the system

$$A^TAx=A^Tb$$

We would need to invert $A^TA$ at this point, but we know that since the rank of $A$ is 2, the rank of $A^TA$ can't be larger than 2. Thus, $A^TA$, which is a 3 by 3 matrix, isn't invertible.

If we think about this problem geometrically, what is it that impedes the projection of $A^Tb$ onto the column space of $A^TA$? Ie, geometrically, why do we need to start with an $A$ that has independent columns?

Comment: Nothing impedes the projection — just drop a redundant column. The system is consistent, regardless, so take the solution $\bar x$ of smallest length.

Comment: Okay, I should rephrase my question. I know that we can project $b$ onto the subspace spanned by the columns of $A$: just drop a column. But my question is, why do we need to drop the column? I can see algebraically why we can't compute a solution (we would need to invert $A^TA$). Is there a geometric reason (ie, an explanation likely involving reasoning about linear combinations) that doesn't allow a non-full-rank matrix $A$?

Comment: Please accept the answer once you are satisfied. You've used this site enough to know that clogging it up with satisfactorily answered questions that appear unanswered isn't good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We certainly do not need to start with a matrix $A$ whose columns are linearly independent. It just makes it easy to write down a formula for the unique solution. However, of course we do not need independent columns in order for the projection of the vector $b$ onto the column space of $A$ to exist (and be uniquely defined).

First, $A^\top Ax = A^\top b$ is consistent, independent of the rank of $A$. Second, any solution will be of the form $x=x_0+u$ for any particular solution $x_0$ and any $u\in N(A^\top A) = N(A)$. If we choose $x_0\in R(A^\top A)$,$^*$ then $x_0$ will be the shortest possible solution. But it's quite irrelevant: The projection of $b$ onto $C(A)$ is the vector $Ax$ for *any* solution $x$ of the normal equations. Indeed, $A(x_0+u) = Ax_0 + Au = Ax_0$, since $u\in N(A)$.

If you're interested, go investigate the pseudoinverse. This has a number of applications in numerical computations, and is easily computable from the SVD decomposition. But it's really not needed here.

$^*$ $R(B)$ denotes the row space of $B$. This is consistent with Strang's texts (and with my own), but for many people it signifies the column space. Isn't notation wonderful?